# React native Android studio not installed even when it is

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, native

$ npx react-native doctor
⠸ Running diagnostics...* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

- daemon started successfully
  Common
  ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
  ✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies

Android
✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

I am expecting to start my react-native app in linux fedora, installed the app and required SDK [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haEgO.png)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxdHU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/403OV.png)

Comment: I don't quite get what your actual issue is. Are you getting any errors somewhere? If  you do, please post those with a blockquote formatting. Please format your question as well. What does those checks and crosses mean? Use new lines to separate the items a check or cross represents